# What's Our Elevator Pitch?

Tags: discussion, 7-essential-metas, site-promotion

Reading [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/):

> Tell us what your community is about in one brief sentence!

So what's our one-liner?

Comment: Where can we see other SEs'?

Comment: @msh210 You can find the equivalent of this question, asked and answered on the universe of beta-SEs back in October, [here](http://stackexchange.com/search?q=%22elevator+pitch%22)

Comment: @IsaacMoses, I didn't look at all of those, but for the ones I looked at, I see discussions, but no decisions, and no implementations (i.e., I don't see any of the elevator pitches actually used anywhere. For example, if I choose to add a link to `http://english.stackexchange.com` as my [Facebook](http://fb.com) status, then Facebook gets "This is a collaboratively edited question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts. It's 100% free, no registration required." from somewhere as a summary (no idea where it gets that from: [continued]

Comment: [continued] there's no HTML meta tag in [the page](http://english.stackexchange.com). But that's another question). That long thing is not [the elevator pitch anyone picked](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/352)). Where are these elevator pitches _used_?

Comment: @msh210 Good question.

Comment: @msh210, If we have a nice tagline, we could certainly stick it in the FAQ. It could also go in promotional materials (e.g. press releases). Also, when it comes time to hire a graphic designer to make a site design, it may be possible to incorporate a tagline into the design. Finally, this discussion could be useful in helping the community determine precisely what this site is about. (Although that should also happen in other meta-questions.)

Answer (score 5):

Here are some ideas to get the juices flowing. I wouldn't choose any of these as a final choice.

- Judaism.SE gives you the chance to share your curiosity and knowledge about all things Jewish with a crowd of other sharers. At the same time, you get to help enrich the Internet with a repository of Jewish information expressed in the language of people who want to know it.

  *This is from early promotional writing I did for mi.yodeya. Pretty dry and long-winded.*
- An "Ask the Rabbi" site without the rabbi.

  *I realize there are unfortunate potential implications in this one.*
- Who knows Judaism? The crowd at Judaism.SE knows Judaism.

  *Of course, this one works much better with "mi.yodeya.com."*
- Ask two Jews, get three opinions, whenever you're ready.
- The ultimate back-of-the-shul kibitz-fest.
- "Ibaya Lehu" for large values of "hu"

  *Only works for people familiar with Talmudic Aramaic. Actually, if this site was just targeted to such people, IbaeiLehu.com would be a cute name, albeit even harder on the spelling intuition.*
- Your giant, online beit midrash.

  *More respectful but more jargony than "back-of-the-shul."*
- Learn in public. Make a kiddush Hashem.

Comment: Oy, the latter two of your suggestions are kind of depressing.

Comment: @WAF, I've suggested five so far. Which do you mean?

Comment: @WAF If you mean the "Ask the Rabbi" one, it doesn't exactly capture what's going on here. I just threw it out there in the spirit of brainstorming.

Comment: @IsaacMoses - Actually the back-of-the-shul one and the 3 opinions one.

Comment: @WAF Interesting. Why do you find those depressing?

Comment: @IsaacMoses - They are sad indices of the ideal of _hagdalas_ and _ha'adaras Torah_ .

Comment: Yeah, I don't like those two, either. The two-three one reinforces a stereotype, and the shul one a behavior, I'm not fond of.

Comment: @WAF and @msh210, If you think they're truly offensive, I'm willing to remove/edit/disclaimer them. The two-three one, in my view, is an irreverent reference to the ability of a Halachic thinker to internalize "Eilu Ve'eilu." Anyway, now that you're thinking about this (which was my goal), please consider adding your own ideas, even if they're off the wall.

Comment: I like the "giant online Bet Midrash", was starting to think along those lines... (I also like the two-three, but I realize it's not very practical).

Answer (score 5):

- The give-a-question-take-a-question of Jewish learning

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by zaq's [work](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319/lets-design-an-ad-for-this-site/324#324) on an ad idea, and some of the ideas here:

- Ask Jewish. Answer Jewish. Learn with the crowd.
- Jewish questions. Jewish answers. Learning with the crowd.
- Jewish questions. Jewish answers. Learn with the crowd.

Answer (score 4):

What the Talmud might have been like if they'd had the Internet.

(Okay, a little flip, and of course אם הראשונים כמלאכים...)

Answer (score 2):

- One big happy chavrusa-schaft.

Too jargony by far as is, but I like how it distinguishes the ask-the-rabbi sites from this one.

Comment: Is there an un-jargony and yet distinctly Jewish way to get at the "Chavrusa" or "Beit Midrash" idea?

Answer (score 2):

- ומחבירי יותר מרבותי.‏

A little dangerous, this one; plus, it's in Hebrew.

Comment: A little dangerous?

Comment: @yydl: One needs a _rav_, of course, and that line can be misread as implying otherwise.

Comment: whoops. Meant to say "a **little** dangerous?"

Comment: Well, _Rav Chanina_ meant that a peer will challenge what someone said in a way a teacher won't, causing him to come to a clearer understanding. (See _Maharsha_.) If the line is used for this site, it'd be interpreted as meaning that a peer can provide information a teacher won't, so... you're right: it's more than a little dangerous. `:-)` Feel free to downvote. `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

- Ask and answer questions on Jewish life and learning.
- Ask and answer questions on traditional Judaism.
- Ask and answer questions on orthodox Judaism.

(and any of those with "Answer and ask" instead) sound good to me, but, well, I'm boring.

Answer (score 1):

- thou shall answer a question about Judaism, or at least ask two.
- thou shall learn about Judaism.