# Should we create an audio promo and target podcasts/radio?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, podcast

Many podcasts are willing to air promos for related sites (mostly podcasts, but not always), often for no cost or just for reciprocity.

Should we create a short audio promo for Judaism.SE and try to get it onto some Jewish podcasts and radio shows?

If so, would you like to draft a script for it? You can get some inspiration for verbiage from [this discussion](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83/whats-our-elevator-pitch).

If so, which podcasts and radio shows should we target? Bonus points if you know someone working on them. Actually, we could target people working on such media even without a promo, just to get them to try the site and mention it themselves on their shows.