# What "prosumerist" vision or idea is exemplified here? / Let's make a winning video

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

This year's [Jewish Futures Competition](http://www.jesna.org/jewishfutures/competition) is soliciting four-minute videos that answer the question:

> **How will Jewish life, living and learning change as we move to a society in which individuals are not only consumers of information and culture, but also producers of their own and others' experiences?**
>
> The submissions should promote a clear **vision** or **idea** in response to this question. Although the submissions may refer to specific projects or programs it is the **vision** or **idea** that should be the focus of the presentation.

Winners of this competition will be flown to the Jewish Federations [General Assembly](http://www.generalassembly.org/) conference in Denver in November, 2011 to deliver a ten-minute presentation based on the video to the [Jewish Futures Conference](http://www.jesna.org/jewishfutures/competition), whose theme is "*The Jewish Prosumer: The Move from Consumer to Producer in Jewish Life and Learning*."

---

Naturally, this all sounds quite relevant to what we're doing here. If we could make one of these videos and end up addressing this conference, it would garner a great deal of attention for our community.

- What clear vision or idea about Jewish individuals as both consumers and producers can we express, in light of what's going on here?
- What are some points that a video expressing this vision or idea ought to make?
- Does anyone here know how to make a nice video?

Comment: Are you suggesting a video _of_ what goes on here (screenshots and maybe a couple animations, with cool transitions) or _inspired by_ what goes on here (actors exemplifying the discussions and edifications)?

Comment: @WAF I'm open to anything that fits the criteria of the contest. My initial thought would be a simple slideshow with voiceover, but that's partly because that's what I could see myself possibly trying to tackle. If you have ideas about either content or format, please post an answer!

Comment: Too localized?​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @DoubleAA, Yes.

Answer (score 2):

One interesting point to consider is that this "prosumerism" concept has existed for ages in the form of [chavruta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chavruta) learning. [One](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83/whats-our-elevator-pitch/116#116) [spin](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83/whats-our-elevator-pitch/131#131) on what we have here is that it's like lots of people joining in a massive, flowing, chavruta partnership.

---

Meaty idea: *Jewish learning traditionally happens in a continuum between chavruta relationships and teacher-student relationships. Decentralized online tools help us refresh the chavruta concept in exciting new ways, but the teacher-student concept requires more work.*

- Traditional modes of Jewish learning, and the role and benefits of each

  - Chavruta

    - Also beit midrash for massive peer learning - "ibaey lehu"
    - Sources
  - Teacher/Student

    - Sources
- J.SE as a case study of refereshed chavruta model

  - What SE is

    - With emphasis on peer learning and community of experts aspects
  - Why J.SE fits this model so well

    - Chavruta learning
    - Plurality of valid answers
    - Community of experts thanks to "Ki heim chayyeinu"
- Challenges to teacher/student model on the Internet and some ideas for mitigation

  - Website as posek

    - various mitigations on J.SE
  - Guidance about what to be learning
  - Decentralized, transitory communities
  - Ano/pseudonymity
- Conclude on reiteration of open questions

Comments, edits, and alternatives welcome. I envision this outline initially containing much more than would fit into four minutes.